# How to add a node at specified index in LinkedList implementation

Tags: java, list, implementation

So I am implementing a LinkedList from scratch and one method, insertAt(int index, T elem), is really giving me a headache. The method is supposed to insert a node at the specified index and move the rest of the list accordingly. My implementation seems to just copy and paste existing nodes. Any help on what I am doing wrong? (use cases below)

Let me know if it would help to include the interface notes or the full class:

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

private Node<T> first;
private Node<T> last;
private int counter;

public LinkedList() {
}

@Override
public ListInterface<T> insertAt(int index, T elem) {
    if(index > counter) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(null, elem, null);
    if(counter == 0) {
        first = last = node;
    }
    else {
        if(index == 0) {
            node.next = first;
            first.prev = node;
            first = node;
        }
        else if(index  == counter) {
            node.prev = last;
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else {
            Node<T> current = this.first;

            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            node.next = current;
            node.prev = current.prev;
            current.prev.next = node;
        }
    }
    counter++;
    return this;
}
```

**Node Class:**

```
public class Node<T> {

public T data;
public Node<T> next;
public Node<T> prev;

public Node(Node<T> prev, T data, Node<T> next){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}

public Node() {

}
```

**Usage Example #1 (Wrong Answers):**

```
      LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList <String>();
      list.insertFirst("p");
      list.insertFirst("a");
      list.insertFirst("e");
      list.insertFirst("h");

      list.insertAt(2, "A");
```

**Console:**

Before: {h, e, a, p}

After: {h, e, e, a, p}

**What Console SHOULD BE:**

Before: {h, e, a, p}

After: {h, e, A, a, p}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current.prev = node;` you lost this one while `0 < index < counter`

i test your code, seems works:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;
    private int     counter;

    public LinkedList() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.insertFirst("p");
        list.insertFirst("a");
        list.insertFirst("e");
        list.insertFirst("h");

        list.insertAt(2, "A");
        for (Node n = list.first; n != null; n = n.next) {
            System.out.println(n.data);
        }
    }

    private void insertFirst(T s) {
        insertAt(0, s);
    }

    public LinkedList<T> insertAt(int index, T elem) {
        if (index > counter) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(null, elem, null);
        if (counter == 0) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            if (index == 0) {
                node.next = first;
                first.prev = node;
                first = node;
            } else if (index == counter) {
                node.prev = last;
                last.next = node;
                last = node;
            } else {
                Node<T> current = this.first;

                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                node.next = current;
                node.prev = current.prev;
                current.prev.next = node;
                current.prev = node;
            }
        }
        counter++;
        return this;
    }
}

class Node<T> {

    public T       data;
    public Node<T> next;
    public Node<T> prev;

    public Node(Node<T> prev, T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public Node() {

    }
}
```